# Get [PrologueSnippet] to work on properties

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm bindings libraries to monotouch. As `NullReferenceException` are a really bad thing to happen on monotouch, I'd like to prevent it by throwing a `System.InvalidOperationException` while accessing a property that'll throw.

For methods, I'm using `[PrologueSnippetAttribute]`. but for obvious reasons, it does not work on properties. How could I have the same behavior for properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `SnippetAttribute`, from which `PrologueSnippetAttribute` inherits, mismatch the `btouch` ([generator.cs](https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/generator.cs)) source code.

The generator only process the attributes on the methods, not the attributes (even if the attribute is marked with `AttributeTargets.Property`). So you need to do something like:

```
[Export ("position")]
PointF Position {
    [PrologueSnippet ("if (!isInitialized) throw new InvalidOperationException ();")]
    get;
    [PrologueSnippet ("if (!isInitialized) throw new InvalidOperationException ();")]
    set;
}
```

which is better than duplicating the property (with an `[Internal]` version). I *believe* the reason is that, most of the time, the same logic can't be used for getter and setters.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I could mark the property [Internal] and write a public proxy for it as extra code, like this:

in ApiDefinition.cs

```
...
[Export ("position")]
[Internal]
PointF PositionInt { get; set; }
...
```

then in Extra.cs

```
...
public PointF Position {
    get {
        if (!isInitialized)
            throw new InvalidOperationException ();
        return PositionInt;
    }
    set {
        if (!isInitialized)
            throw new InvalidOperationException ();
        PositionInt = value
    }
}
...
```

But something quicker and more automated would be good